# Change Joomla's 'Login to Readmore' url from login page to register page?

Tags: joomla

I have a blog page on Joomla which shows 'register to read more' link after each articles intro text.

Clicking this brings the user to a login page, with no 'register' option.

How would I change this to bring a user to the register page instead, and preferably revert the user back to the article after login? I have a login box on the register page so it allows the user to choose either login or register.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Joomla 2.5 and you don't see a link saying something like "Don't have an account?" then you have User Registration turned off.

Go to the `Users` menu and select `User Manager` and then click on the `Options` icon in the toolbar. Under the `Component` tab set the first option `Allow User Registration` to `Yes`.

Save you changes and then click on one of the "Register to read more…" links and you should now see the extra "Don't have an account?"

If you want more than the basic Joomla! options for site access then you may want to look at the [Joomla! Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/) (JED) and [the section on Site Access](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access)

Comment: Registration is turned on.  I have new users on my site on a daily basis. I've actually realised that I can't login using the form on the page, but I can from my login module on other pages.  I should have noted I'm using community builder so how can I change this login page to the CB one?

Comment: If you're using CB that will depend on the plugins and setup you're best of asking the forums http://www.joomlapolis.com/forum/index